# Calculate intermediate week days between two week days In PHP

Tags: php, weekday

Given two weekdays: Monday, Wednesday.

How do you get the intermediate days in that array? 
Answer: Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday.

Case 2: from Monday to Monday
Answer: Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday, Monday

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: You can create an array which lists Monday through Sunday twice, loop it, if day equals start day then begin outputting, stop checking start day, if day equals end day then stop looping.

Comment: Saturday and Sunday are not considered "week days", they are "week ends". So should those be omitted from the output in your Monday to Monday example?

Comment: In this case, Saturday and Sunday should also be considered

Comment: Great, try out my suggestion and come back with your attempted code if you get stuck.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I started my solution using the idea you had for it, but that seemed really complicated actually. So I thought of a different way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution is more about moving the internal pointer of the array until the margins are found and pushing the elements between margins into another result array. Can be used regardless of what data is in the initial array.

```
function getDaysInBetween($start, $end)
    {
        $weekdays = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];

        $start_found = false;

        $days = [];

        while(true) {
            $next = next($weekdays);
            $day = (empty($day) || !$next)?reset($weekdays):$next;

            if($day === $start) $start_found = true;

            if($start_found) {
                $days[] = $day;
                if($day===$end && count($days)>1) return implode(", ",$days);
            }

        }

    }
```

Live demo here: https://3v4l.org/D5063

Comment: I initially was going to do something like this, but I got stuck. I see you used `count($days)>1`, if I had thought of that I would have had a similar solution :D

Answer (score 2):

I've created this function which does this, and the comments step you through how it was done.

```
function list_days($start, $end) {

    //convert day "word" to it's given number
    //Monday = 1, Tuesday = 2 ... Sunday = 7
    $start_n = date('N', strtotime($start));
    $end_n = $end_range = date('N', strtotime($end));

    //we also set $end_range above, by default it's set to the $end day number, 
    //but if $start and $end are the same it will be changed later.

    //create an empty output array
    $output = [];

    //determine end_range for the for loop
    //if $start and $end are not the same, the $end_range is simply the number of $end (set earlier)
    if($start_n == $end_n) {

        //if $start and $end ARE the same, we know there is always 7 days between the days
        //So we just add 7 to the start day number.
        $end_range = $start_n + 7;
    }

    //loop through, generate a list of days
    for ($x = $start_n; $x <= $end_range; $x++) {

        //convert day number back to the readable text, and put it in the output array
        $output[] = date('l', strtotime("Sunday +{$x} days"));
    }

    //return a string with commas separating the words.
    return implode(', ', $output);
}
```

Usage:

Example 1:

```
echo list_days('Monday', 'Wednesday');
//output: Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday
```

Example 2:

```
echo list_days('Monday', 'Monday');
//output: Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday, Monday
```

Comment: @lolo I actually seem to have made a mistake, check the current code in the answer to fix it. Basically the mistake made it so if you did Tuesday->Tuesday, Wednesday->Wednesday, etc (Basically anything other than Monday->Monday), it would return incorrectly.